# xargs git: skip user input

Tags: git, xargs, less

I have an `xargs` function that calls git commands recursively.

When I now call `gitr log` I have to hit enter until the end or q to get the next `xargs` call to run.

Can I tell `xargs` to skip user input or output everything of `less` at once?

Comment: You can call `git` with the `--no-pager` option if you want it to dump out everything without running `less`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `git` with the `--no-pager` option if you want it to dump out everything without running `less`. Here are details from the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/):

> --no-pager
>
> > Do not pipe git output into a pager.

Answer (score 0):

try redirecting stdin or stdout or both.

eg:

```
gitr log < /dev/null | cat
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't xargs that's prompting you, it's less. And less isn't invoked by xargs, but by git.

Each invocation of git operates on one repository at a time, so if you want to operate on multiple repositories, you'll need to tell git not to invoke a pager. You may want to invoke a pager manually though.

Here's some untested proof-of-concept code that causes git not to invoke a pager, but invokes a pager on the output from all the git invocations when called interactively. Your code goes into the `run_git` auxiliary function.

```
gitr () {
  if [ -t 1 ]; then
    run_git \
      -ccolor.branch=always "$@" -ccolor.grep=always -ccolor.showbranch=always -ccolor.status=always \
      | ${GIT_PAGER:-less -r}
  else
    run_git "$@"
  fi
}
```